# Updating OpenLayers plugin

Tags: openlayers, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I just installed QGIS 3.6. How can I update OpenLayers plugin? I tried to georeferenced Google Earth but I was not able to source Google OpenLayers plugins. I wish I can get a link to download.

Comment: Try instead the plugin Quick Map Services, it's the same but for new QGIS releases.